# Curvature of curves through a point of a surface smoothly embedded in Euclidean space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

The curve C() drawn on a smoothly embedded surface  in 3-space — where C() is defined as the intersection of  with a 2-plane perpendicular to  at P — leaving the point P at angle  will have the well-known formula for curvature:

k()  =   k<sub>1</sub> cos<sup>2</sup>() + k<sub>2</sub> sin<sup>2</sup>()

at P, where k<sub>1</sub> and k<sub>2</sub> are the principal curvatures of  at P.

Likewise, we can look at a point P of a smoothly embedded surface  in Euclidean n-space, and consider the curves C() that are each the intersection of  with a hyperplane that is perpendicular to  at P and ask what their curvatures are as a function of angle .

Does there exist a formula (like k() = k<sub>1</sub> cos<sup>2</sup>() + k<sub>2</sub> sin<sup>2</sup>(), or different) for the curvatures k() of the curves C() in this case?

And what about the special case where  is a Riemann surface holomorphically embedded in **C**<sup>m</sup> = **R**<sup>2m</sup>?

Comment: You might want to look at the second fundamental form, which becomes vector valued in codimension more than 1

Comment: I certainly expect the answer is essentially some symmetric combination of second derivatives.

Comment: Since hyperplanes are totally geodesic: if you denote by $II_p(v,w)$ the vector valued second fundamental form of $\Sigma$ at the point $p$, and  $v$ the tangent vector to $C$, then the curvature vector (the acceleration of $C$ with unit-speed parametrization) is exactly $II_p(v,v)$. You don't always as nice a formula as $k_1\cos^2(\theta) + k_2\sin^2(\theta)$, since the different (vector) components of $k$ may not be simultaneously diagonalizable (so what you call $\theta$ may be not well-defined).

Comment: For that matter, the principal extrinsic curvatures are also not always well-defined. The same problem should still persist in the holomorphic setting.

Comment: At any given point P of the surface : What I call  is always well-defined (relative to a choice of reference angle). After all, the surface is embedded, so it has a well-defined 2-plane T in n-space as its tangent plane, as well as a well-defined normal (n-2)-space N. So the sum of N and any tangent line to  at P is a hyperplane perpendicular to T, intersecting it in a line. The angle between any two such lines is well-defined, and there are 2π worth of tangent rays.

Comment: Plus everything is local, so orientation is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be a unit tangent vector at $p$.
The curvature $k$ in the direction of $u$ is $|\mathrm{I\!I}_p(u,u)|$, where $\mathrm{I\!I}_p$ is the second fundamental form at $p$;
it is a quadratic form on tangent plane $\mathrm{T}_p$ with values in the normal space $\mathrm{N}_p$.

We may write $\mathrm{I\!I}_p$ in a basis $e_1,\dots,e_{n-2}$ of $\mathrm{N}_p$,
$$\mathrm{I\!I}_p=s_1\cdot e_1+\dots+s_{n-2}\cdot e_{n-2};$$
so,
$$k=\sqrt{s_1(u,u)^2+\dots+s_{n-2}(u,u)^2}.$$

Each form $s_i$ is diagonalizable, denote by $a_i$ and $b_i$ its eigenvalues;
let $\phi_i$ be the angle to the first eigenvector.
Then we get
$$k=\sqrt{\sum_i(a_i\cdot \cos(\theta-\phi_i)^2+b_i\cdot \sin(\theta-\phi_i)^2)^2}.$$
(I do not think you need it, but that is what you asked for.)

By the way, the image of $\mathrm{I\!I}_p$ is at most 3-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{N}_p$. So you may reduce number of terms to three.